# InitialContext.doLookup Invokes Bean's Constructor Twice

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I have a SFSB called `RandomBean` which has a default constructor, `@PostConstruct`, `@PreDestroy` and `@Remove` methods. There's a simple counter in the constructor.

```
@Stateful
public class RandomBean {

    public static int c = 0;

    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RandomBean.class);

    private Random r;

    private int cc;

    public RandomBean() {
        c += 1;
        cc = c;
        r = new Random();
        logger.info("Random constructed: " + cc);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        logger.info("Random started: " + cc);
    }

    public int nextInt() {
        logger.info("Random invoked: " + cc);
        return r.nextInt();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        logger.info("Random destroyed: " + cc);
    }

    @Remove
    public void remove() {
        logger.info("removed: " + cc);
    }
}
```

I also have a servlet which performs a lookup for this bean and calls its `nextInt` method.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    logger.info("Doing get");
    try {
        RandomBean r = InitialContext.doLookup("java:module/RandomBean");
        logger.info("get! " + r.nextInt());
        r.remove();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What confuses me is that the `RandomBean`'s constructor appears to be called twice:

```
02:13:09,558 INFO  [org.sokolas.model.HelloServlet] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Doing get
02:13:09,559 INFO  [org.sokolas.model.RandomBean] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Random constructed: 1
02:13:09,560 INFO  [org.sokolas.model.RandomBean] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Random constructed: 2
02:13:09,561 INFO  [org.sokolas.model.RandomBean] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Random started: 2
02:13:09,561 INFO  [org.sokolas.model.RandomBean] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Random invoked: 2
02:13:09,562 INFO  [org.sokolas.model.HelloServlet] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) get! -2028573462
02:13:09,562 INFO  [org.sokolas.model.RandomBean] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) removed: 2
02:13:09,563 INFO  [org.sokolas.model.RandomBean] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Random destroyed: 2
```

Is this behaviour intended? Should I put all the initialization in the `@PostConstruct` method and don't use the constructor?
I'm using JBoss EAP 6.2.

Answer (score 1):

The container might decide to precreate additional instances of the bean implementation.
At instance creation time it is not bound to any client session.

You should put all initialization logic into the ejbCreate/@Init or @PostConstruct methods.
If you look at what a SFSB may do in the EJB 3.1 spec section 4.6.1, you even see that you are not allowed to do any invocation of container services in the constructor but a lot more in the callbacks.